# What exactly does git download when you clone and how to reduce the size of it?

Tags: git

I'm looking forward to reducing the download times for people who will be using my repository overseas. I've now received complaints about this being too slow.

I've ran a script on the repository to look into all objects and find out what objects are the largest. Here's the final table:

```
|     size |     pack | SHA      | location                                     |
|----------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------|
|  7755956 |  7715996 | ecb5febf | media/promo/some.mp4                         |
|  7082482 |  7019098 | 108b2909 | media/promo/some.webm                        |
|  5154689 |  5079200 | 1c20bd3b | media/promo/some.ogv                         |
|  3889885 |  3657066 | 2ad1b747 | AdModule/AdModule/media/other.mp4            |
|  3799591 |  3772833 | 7a901d41 | AdModule/AdModule/media/other.ogv            |
|  2130845 |  2119014 | e034cb72 | media/promo/trailer.webm                     |
|  2130845 |  2119014 | e034cb72 | media/promo/trailer.webm                     |
|  2130845 |  2119014 | e034cb72 | media/promo/trailer.webm                     |
|  1912643 |  1806844 | cbd2562f | media/promo/trailer.mp4                      |
|  1912643 |  1806844 | cbd2562f | media/promo/trailer.mp4                      |
|  1912643 |  1806844 | cbd2562f | media/promo/trailer.mp4                      |
|  1371459 |  1356916 | bbb2c932 | AdModule/AdModule/media/trailer.webm         |
|   277981 |    80590 | 61375a0c | AdModule/AdModule/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js    |
|   260304 |    47616 | f4427aed | AdModule/packages/jQuery.1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1- |
```

Now, I could probably loose `some.mp4`, `some.webm` etc because in the course of the development they were replaced by other videos and other developer will never need the older videos.

I've never re-written git history / squashed commits. So, I'm afraid to do it :)

When I look at the time and reported size of the download that happens when I execute `git clone` I don't receive nearly as much data as there is stored in the repository (perhaps only a tenth of it).

So, here's my question: will my attempt to delete the commits containing the large blobs benefit my case, as in reducing the download time? If not, what can I possibly do to reduce the download times?

PS. I have the complete SHA sums, they are truncated in the table for readability.

---

Here's another table that shows the size of the files actually in `.git` directory (which is a lot less then the total size of everything that needs to be in history of this repo):

```
|     size | file                                                                 |
|----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    46802 | projects/take5/sdk/.git                                              |
|    46680 | projects/take5/sdk/.git/objects                                      |
|    42268 | projects/take5/sdk/.git/objects/pack                                 |
|    20164 | projects/take5/sdk/.git/objects/pack/pack-594c78df5239b9e0dcd1014ac8 |
|     9712 | projects/take5/sdk/.git/objects/pack/pack-66fbcdd8ee5685720eb77a979a |
|     4176 | projects/take5/sdk/.git/objects/pack/pack-f6f37936674d8f016b58dce74e |
|     4176 | projects/take5/sdk/.git/objects/pack/pack-9f11f69dc046de80640de5d265 |
|     3960 | projects/take5/sdk/.git/objects/pack/pack-56985618be0c8c8596d12111fe |
|      551 | projects/take5/sdk/.git/objects/b9                                   |
```

Running `git gc` I could shave off about 11 Mb of the total size.

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite history to exclude that files with filter-branch.
read this for a complete tutorial: http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/2-permanently-remove-files-and-folders-from-a-git-repository

keep in mind that you will end up with a incompatible repository and all existing users need to re-clone the new repo.

ps: yes, this will reduce the download size. git downloads the full history of all files when cloning (that why you have to completely remove it with filter-branch to get any savings). as some compression takes place when storing the history it is expected that the object files are smaller than the actual checkout (if you do not have too much history), but a factor of 1/10 seems odd, especially if it is movies that do not compress well.

Comment: Thanks, interesting read (I've learned from the comments about `git gc` - which is also nice). But I would actually like to avoid rewriting, if possible. Instead, I'd like to reduce the time it takes to do the initial cloning (the other developers don't need the entire repository, neither the whole history - just a tiny part of it). Judging from how cloning doesn't bring you all of the repo, I'd suspect there may be some other way to reducing that size. Perhaps cleaning the master branch? Maybe there's a way to only clone selected branch? I want check that first.

Comment: "cloning doesn't bring you all of the repo" IT DOES. on the other hand, if "(the other developers don't need the entire repository, neither the whole history - just a tiny part of it)" then you might want to learn about shallow clones, but they do not give you much benefit ( http://blogs.gnome.org/simos/2009/04/18/git-clones-vs-shallow-git-clones/ ) and really suck should you ever want to contribute back.

Comment: Oh... now I see! Well, I've imagined one more digit in the size report... well :( Yes, I was wrong where I said it is about tenth of the size - it is exactly that size, so, yes. Probably I'll have to move on with the filtering / rewriting.

Comment: I was trying to follow the instructions on that blog, but I am still here... after using `git filter-branch -f --tree-filter "rm video.mp4"` on all branches, the index file didn't get any smaller. I've ran `git gc` afterwards - no change. `git verify-pack` shows that the blob is still there. What do I miss?

Comment: try cloning the repository locally and see if you still end up with that file.